# Getting nans after applying softmax

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to develop a deep Markov Model using following tutorial:

https://pyro.ai/examples/dmm.html

This model parameterises transitions and emissions with using a neural network and for variational inference part they use RNN to map observable 'x' to latent space. And in order to ensure that their model is learning something they try to maximise ELBO or minimise negative ELBO. They refer to negative ELBO as NLL.

I am basically converting pyro code to pure pytorch. And I've put together pretty much every thing. However, now I want to get a reconstruct error on test sequences. My input is one hot encoding of my sequences and it is of shape (500,1900,4) where 4 refers to number of features and 1900 is sequence length, and 500 refers to total number of examples.

The way I am generating data is:

```python
generation model p(x_{1:T} | z_{1:T}) p(z_{1:T})

batch_size, _, x_dim = x.size() # number of time steps we need to process in the mini-batch
T_max = x_lens.max()
z_prev = self.z_0.expand(batch_size, self.z_0.size(0)) # set z_prev=z_0 to setup the recursive conditioning in p(z_t|z_{t-1})
for t in range(1, T_max + 1):
    # sample z_t ~ p(z_t | z_{t-1}) one time step at a time
    z_t, z_mu, z_logvar = self.trans(z_prev) # p(z_t | z_{t-1})
    p_x_t = F.softmax(self.emitter(z_t),dim=-1)  # compute the probabilities that parameterize the bernoulli likelihood
    safe_tensor = torch.where(torch.isnan(p_x_t), torch.zeros_like(p_x_t), p_x_t)
    print('generate p_x_t : ',safe_tensor)
    x_t = torch.bernoulli(safe_tensor) #sample observe x_t according to the bernoulli distribution p(x_t|z_t)
    print('generate x_t : ',x_t)
    z_prev = z_t
```

So my emissions are being defined by Bernoulli distribution. And I use softmax in order to compute probabilities that parameterise the Bernoulli likelihood. And then I sample my observables x_t according the Bernoulli distribution.

At first when I ran my model, I was getting nans at times and so I introduced the line (show below) in order to convert nans to zero:

```python
safe_tensor = torch.where(torch.isnan(p_x_t), torch.zeros_like(p_x_t), p_x_t)
```

However, after 1 epoch or so 'x_t' that I sample, this tensor is just zero. Basically, what I want is that after applying softmax, I want my function to pick the highest probability and give me the corresponding label for it which is either of the 4 features. But I get nans and then when I convert all nans to zero, I end up getting all zeros in all tensors after 1 epoch or so.

Also, when I look at p_x_t tensor I get probabilities that add up to one. But when I look at x_t tensor it gives me 0's all the way. So for example:

```python
p_x_t : tensor([[0.2168, 0.2309, 0.2555, 0.2967]
.....], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SWhereBackward>)

generate x_t : tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0.],...
], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<BernoulliBackward0>)
```

Here fourth label/feature is giving me highest probability. Shouldn't the x_t tensor give me 1 at least in that position so be like:

```python
generate x_t : tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1.],...
], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<BernoulliBackward0>)
```

How can I get rid of this problems?

**EDIT**

My transition (which is called as self.trans in generate function mentioned above):

```python
class GatedTransition(nn.Module):
    """
    Parameterizes the gaussian latent transition probability `p(z_t | z_{t-1})`
    See section 5 in the reference for comparison.
    """
    def __init__(self, z_dim, trans_dim):
        super(GatedTransition, self).__init__()
        self.gate = nn.Sequential( 
            nn.Linear(z_dim, trans_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(trans_dim, z_dim),
            nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        )
        self.proposed_mean = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(z_dim, trans_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(trans_dim, z_dim)
        )           
        self.z_to_mu = nn.Linear(z_dim, z_dim)
        # modify the default initialization of z_to_mu so that it starts out as the identity function
        self.z_to_mu.weight.data = torch.eye(z_dim)
        self.z_to_mu.bias.data = torch.zeros(z_dim)
        self.z_to_logvar = nn.Linear(z_dim, z_dim)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, z_t_1):
        """
        Given the latent `z_{t-1}` corresponding to the time step t-1
        we return the mean and scale vectors that parameterize the (diagonal) gaussian distribution `p(z_t | z_{t-1})`
        """        
        gate = self.gate(z_t_1) # compute the gating function
        proposed_mean = self.proposed_mean(z_t_1) # compute the 'proposed mean'
        mu = (1 - gate) * self.z_to_mu(z_t_1) + gate * proposed_mean # compute the scale used to sample z_t, using the proposed mean from
        logvar = self.z_to_logvar(self.relu(proposed_mean)) 
        epsilon = torch.randn(z_t_1.size(), device=z_t_1.device) # sampling z by re-parameterization
        z_t = mu + epsilon * torch.exp(0.5 * logvar)    # [batch_sz x z_sz]

        if torch.isinf(z_t).any().item():
            print('something is infinity')
            print('z_t : ',z_t)
            print('logvar : ',logvar)
            print('epsilon : ',epsilon)
            print('mu : ',mu)

        return z_t, mu, logvar
```

I do not get any inf in z_t tensor when doing training and validation. Only during testing. This is how I am training, validating and testing my model:

```python
    for epoch in range(config['epochs']):

        train_loader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_set, batch_size=config['batch_size'], shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
        train_data_iter=iter(train_loader)
        n_iters=train_data_iter.__len__()

        epoch_nll = 0.0 # accumulator for our estimate of the negative log likelihood (or rather -elbo) for this epoch
        i_batch=1   
        n_slices=0
        loss_records={}
        while True:            
            try: x, x_rev, x_lens = train_data_iter.next()                  
            except StopIteration: break # end of epoch                 
            x, x_rev, x_lens = gVar(x), gVar(x_rev), gVar(x_lens)

            if config['anneal_epochs'] > 0 and epoch < config['anneal_epochs']: # compute the KL annealing factor            
                min_af = config['min_anneal']
                kl_anneal = min_af+(1.0-min_af)*(float(i_batch+epoch*n_iters+1)/float(config['anneal_epochs']*n_iters))
            else:            
                kl_anneal = 1.0 # by default the KL annealing factor is unity

            loss_AE = model.train_AE(x, x_rev, x_lens, kl_anneal)

            epoch_nll += loss_AE['train_loss_AE']
            i_batch=i_batch+1
            n_slices=n_slices+x_lens.sum().item()

        loss_records.update(loss_AE)   
        loss_records.update({'epo_nll':epoch_nll/n_slices})
        times.append(time.time())
        epoch_time = times[-1] - times[-2]
        log("[Epoch %04d]\t\t(dt = %.3f sec)"%(epoch, epoch_time))
        log(loss_records)
        if args.visual:
            for k, v in loss_records.items():
                tb_writer.add_scalar(k, v, epoch)

        # do evaluation on test and validation data and report results
        if (epoch+1) % args.test_freq == 0:
            save_model(model, epoch)
            #test_loader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_set, batch_size=config['batch_size'], shuffle=False, num_workers=1)
            valid_loader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=valid_set, batch_size=config['batch_size'], shuffle=False, num_workers=1)

            for x, x_rev, x_lens in valid_loader: 
                x, x_rev, x_lens = gVar(x), gVar(x_rev), gVar(x_lens)
                loss,kl_loss = model.valid(x, x_rev, x_lens)
                #print('x_lens sum : ',x_lens.sum().item())
                #print('loss : ',loss)
                valid_nll = loss/x_lens.sum().item()
            log("[Epoch %04d]\t\t(valid_loss = %.8f)\t\t(kl_loss = %.8f)\t\t(valid_nll = %.8f)"%(epoch, loss, kl_loss, valid_nll ))

    test_loader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_set, batch_size=config['batch_size'], shuffle=False, num_workers=1)
    for x, x_rev, x_lens in test_loader: 
        x, x_rev, x_lens = gVar(x), gVar(x_rev), gVar(x_lens)
        loss,kl_loss = model.valid(x, x_rev, x_lens)
        test_nll = loss/x_lens.sum().item()
        model.generate(x, x_rev, x_lens)
        log("[test_nll epoch %08d]  %.8f" % (epoch, test_nll))
```

The test is outside the for loop for epoch. Because I want to test my model on test sequences using generate function. Can you now help me understand if there's something wrong I am doing?

Comment: its possible your values are so large they are causing an overflow in softmax which is resulting in nans. Because softmax is unstable when the logits are too large you could instead try using [`log_softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.log_softmax) which will have the same relative ordering as softmax but doesn't have the same numeric instabilities.

Comment: I tried that as well. But eventually my entire tensor is nan.

Comment: Can you track down the first time a nan value appears and include those values to your question? i.e. What was the first non-nan tensor (`z_t`) for which applying softmax results in nan?

Comment: I looked into z_t and it is 'inf' or '-inf' which gives me nan after applying softmax. I am using softmax in my emission and transition function as well. Should I use log_softmax there as well?

Comment: How can I get rid of 'inf' in my z_t?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the details of the RNN approach you're using, but i think you're one step closer to finding the issue. I think the next step is tracking down the first instance of `inf` in the network and see what is causing that.

Comment: How can I do that exactly? What should I be looking into specifically? I've never worked with pytorch before therefore, having a bit of problem here.

Comment: Given a tensor (let's say `x`) you could check `if torch.isinf(x).any().item():` to see if any of the elements are infinity. When this occurs you could either set a `breakpoint()` to explore the values of your variables using the python debugger or you could print some useful information like the values of the tensor which resulted infinity occuring.

Comment: So I ran my model with bunch of print statements to see why I am getting the error I'm getting like you suggested. Turns out it's only when I'm generating the sequence I get infinity in z_t tensor. I've edited my post (see under EDIT). Where I show you my transition neural network. And another code where I show how I am calling my 'generate function'. Can you tell me why I am getting the error now. I can't really tell why I am getting infinity only when I am using generate function. I